# Split dataframe into two on the basis of date

Tags: python, dataset

I have dataset  with 1000 rows like this

```
 Date,      Cost,         Quantity(in ton),    Source,          Unloading Station
    01/10/2015, 7,            5.416,               XYZ,           ABC
```

i want to split the data on the base of date. For e.g. till date 20.12.2016 is a training data and after that it is test data.

How should i split? Is it possible?

Comment: simple loop would suffice

Comment: Yes, it is possible to split data this way. Whether it's the right thing to do is contextual; your intention already seems to be to split it this way. I'm unclear on the type of answer you are expecting. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: @roganjosh  there is a dataset with above labels( date,cost, quantity,source,destination). Now there is a specific date given (e.g. 1/10/2016), till this date i want my dataset as a training dataset and rest will be training. And on a particular date there are lots of quantity has been sent from source to destination. Just like this, dates are serialized, e.g. from 1/1/2015 to 1/1/2016

Comment: what is the type of your dataset? is it a pandas data frame?

Comment: @kush it's still not a question though, it's just a statement. How is your data read into Python? "How should I split?" is impossible to answer. "is it possible?" - almost certainly "yes". You need to clarify in the question what you are looking to do and, preferably, post what you have tried that doesn't work.

Comment: i was using pandas data frame and it was easy to split it into different sets on the basis of date

Answer (score 18):

You can easily do that by converting your column to pandas to_datetime type and set it as index.

```
import pandas as pd
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index(df['Date'])
df = df.sort_index()
```

Once you have your data in this format, you can simply use date as index for creating partition as follows:

```
# create train test partition
train = df['2015-01-10':'2016-12-20']
test  = df['2016-12-21':]
print('Train Dataset:',train.shape)
print('Test Dataset:',test.shape)
```

Comment: I met similar problems but my Date is already an index just I have different ids with the same interval. How to split this?

Comment: Can you please post a sample dataset?

Comment: Is `df.sort_index()` necessary?

Answer (score 12):

assuming that your data set is pandas data frame and that `Date` column is of `datetime` dtype:

```
split_date = pd.datetime(2016,12,20)

df_training = df.loc[df['Date'] <= split_date]
df_test = df.loc[df['Date'] > split_date]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your date is in standard python datetime format ie. '2016-06-23 23:00:00', you can use the code below

`split_date ='2016-06-23 23:00:00'
train_data = train_data.loc[train_data['Date'] <= split_date]
validation_data = train_data.loc[train_data['Date'] > split_date]`