# Split dataframe on the basis of date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to split a dataframe into two based on date. This has been solved for a related problem here: [Split dataframe into two on the basis of date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37532098/split-dataframe-into-two-on-the-basis-of-date)

My dataframe looks like this:

```
               abcde     col_b
2008-04-10  0.041913  0.227050
2008-04-11  0.041372  0.228116
2008-04-12  0.040835  0.229199
2008-04-13  0.040300  0.230301
2008-04-14  0.039770  0.231421
```

How do I split it based on date (say before 2008-04-12 and after)? When I try this:

```
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df.index) <= split_date]
```

where `split_date` is `datetime.date(2008-04-12)`, I get this error:

```
*** TypeError: <class 'datetime.date'> type object 2008-04-12
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from your code

> where split_date is datetime.date(2008-04-12), I get this error

here `datetime.date()` takes argument as format `2008,4,12` [for more](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html). so you should write

```
split_date = datetime.date(2008,4,12)
```

and as you sample input the first column has no name so you can follow to access the first column like this

```
df[(pd.to_datetime(df[df.columns[0]]) < split_date)]
```

else you give the column name as `"date"` or whatever you want

```
df[(pd.to_datetime(df["date"]) < split_date)]
```

and lastly

`TypeError: <class 'datetime.date'> type object 2008-04-12`

This is occurred basically you try this `datetime object` to the series of `df`

[for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898824/filtering-pandas-dataframes-on-dates)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17338394)

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.

Comment: (@Lundin and @ Sergio),Thanks for good suggestion and I will keep in mind for all next approaches.

Comment: This worked but threw: "FutureWarning: Comparing Series of datetimes with 'datetime.date'.  Currently, the
'datetime.date' is coerced to a datetime. In the future pandas will
not coerce, and a TypeError will be raised. To retain the current
behavior, convert the 'datetime.date' to a datetime with
'pd.Timestamp'.
  split_date = datetime.date(2008,4,12)"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:
Add the label "Date" to the data file for the first column.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

split_date ='2008-04-12'
df_training = df.loc[df['Date'] <= split_date]
df_test = df.loc[df['Date'] > split_date]
print df_test
```

When you do a comparision such as

```
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df.index) <= split_date]
```

both sides must be of same type.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, if you are looking to get the dataframe between two dates you can do this following @R.A.Munna's logic:

```
import datetime

split_date_one = datetime.date(2019,9,26)
split_date_two = datetime.date(2019,10,13)

df= df[(pd.to_datetime(df[df.columns[0]]) >= split_date_one) & (pd.to_datetime(df[df.columns[0]]) <= split_date_two)]
```